# Apply same vertical position as sibling view with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm creating a custom `UITableViewCell`, but I don't think it makes a difference - my question stands alone.

I'm subclassing one of the existing cell styles, and adding one view. The superclass has a view (a `UILabel`) that adjusts its vertical positioning within the cell depending on whether or not there is content in another label. If there is content in the second label, the first label is vertically centered between the second label and the top of the cell view.
If the second label doesn't have any content, the first label is vertically centered between the top and the bottom of the cell view.

I like this behavior. I'm trying to add a third label that is horizontally next to the first label. I've used autolayout constraints to pin the new label to be near the first label, like this:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[firstLabel]-(5)-[thirdLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

This is working fine, but I can't figure out how to do something similar with the vertical position. Ideally, I would "pin" the third label to always be at the same vertical alignment as the first label, no matter what that is, but I don't see how to express that in the visual format language.

As an alternative, figuring out how to replicate the behavior of the first label (adjusting it's vertical alignment based on the presence--or lack of--the second label).

This constraint works to correctly vertically align the new label when the second label *is* present, but it doesn't do anything if the second label is empty on that particular cell:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[thirdLabel][secondLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

How can I express this layout constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Format Language is best used to create constraints aligning items one after the other.

For more complex layouts like the vertical center alignment you are trying to build, you should use `NSLayoutConstraint`'s `constraintWithItem:[...].` method.

Here is what you could do:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:thirdLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:firstLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              multiplier:1
                                constant:0];
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: That worked perfectly - thanks! I've got to stop assuming that just because I don't understand why something exists, it isn't the solution.